# Error in named-checkzone: DNS zone error:( out of zone) has no addresses records (A or AAAA)

Tags: dns, domain, bind, domain-name

I have the same issue as in [Error in named-checkzone](https://superuser.com/questions/1307854/error-in-named-checkzone-dns-zone-error-has-no-address-records-a-or-aaaa). I have cross-checked my zone file and they are properly formatted FQDN.

I checked the zone file using :

```
:/etc/bind$ sudo named-checkzone linuxconfig.org zones/master/db.linuxconfig.org 
zone linuxconfig.org/IN: sample.linuxconfig.org/NS 'ns1.sample.linuxconfig.org' (out of zone) has no addresses records (A or AAAA)
zone linuxconfig.org/IN: loaded serial 1
OK
```

The file: `db.linuxconfig.org.` contains the following:

```
;
; BIND data file for linuxconfig.org
;
$TTL    3h
@       IN      SOA     ns1.linuxconfig.org. admin.linuxconfig.org. (
                          1        ; Serial
                          3h       ; Refresh after 3 hours
                          1h       ; Retry after 1 hour
                          1w       ; Expire after 1 week
                          1h )     ; Negative caching TTL of 1 day
;
@       IN      NS      ns1.linuxconfig.org.    

linuxconfig.org.            IN      MX      10      mail.linuxconfig.org.
linuxconfig.org.            IN      A       192.168.0.19
ns1                         IN      A       92.168.0.10
www                         IN      CNAME   @
mail                        IN      A       12.168.0.10
ftp                         IN      CNAME   linuxconfig.org.
sample                      IN      NS      ns1.sample.linuxconfig.org.
ns1.sample.linuxconfig.org. IN      A       1.1.1.1
```

If I removed the ns1.sample.linuxconfig.org. record then BIND will complain `.. has no REQUIRED GLUE address records`.

Why is the `named-checkzone` complaining when BIND can successfully accept the file and return the records when queried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass `-i local` or `-i local-sibling`, `named-checkzone` will succeed fully. Look in the man page for the explanation of `-i`.

Basically `-i` does post-load zone integrity checks, and defaults to `-i full`:

> Mode "full" checks that delegation NS records refer to A or AAAA record (both in-zone and out-of-zone hostnames). It also checks that glue address records in the zone match those advertised by
>              the child. Mode "local" only checks NS records which refer to in-zone hostnames or that some required glue exists, that is when the nameserver is in a child zone.

First this explains why the zone still loads even if named-checkzone fails in your run: the errors you get come from checks done after the zone, by doing here real DNS queries.

In fact, it tries to query for `ns1.sample.linuxconfig.org` and it fails, hence your error, if you do `ltrace` you can see:

```
getaddrinfo("ns1.sample.linuxconfig.org.", nil, 0x7ffe2c6c4bb0, 0x7ffe2c6c4b78) = -2
```

Comment: Wow, good to know.  For the keywords: this can occur when you're delegating a subdomain and the subdomain isn't set up and answering queries yet.  The delegation can be fine and still throw the errors without `-i local`.